# TSQL Insert Statement with XML

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have a Stored Procedure that is receiving some xml from my tool.

```
 BEGIN
            --Insert Plates
            INSERT INTO licensePlates (carColor, carModel, licensePlate, empID, dateAdded)
            SELECT ParamValues.x2.value('color[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                   ParamValues.x2.value('model[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                   ParamValues.x2.value('licensePlate[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                   @empID,
                   GETDATE()
            FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS ParamValues(x2);

            --Insert Carpool
            INSERT INTO licensePlatesCarpool (licensePlate, empID, dateUpdated)
            SELECT ParamValues.x2.value('licensePlate[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)'),
                   ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)'),
                   GETDATE()
            FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/carPool/employee') AS ParamValues(x2);

        END
```

The XML that is being sent is:

```
            <vehicles>
               <vehicle>
                  <licensePlate>fdg</licensePlate>
                  <model>fg</model>
                  <color>dfg</color>
                  <carPool>
                     <employee>
                        <licensePlate>fdg</licensePlate>
                        <empID>456</empID>
                     </employee>
                     <employee>
                        <licensePlate>fdg</licensePlate>
                        <empID>123</empID>
                     </employee>
                  </carPool>
               </vehicle>
            </vehicles>
```

For some reason, only the top insert statement is actually firing; the other doesn't insert any data even though the table appears to be set up correct.

[image]

Can anyone see anything that I am overlooking that would cause the second insert to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. Wasn't far enough in the XML string yet :)

I changed

```
 FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/carPool/employee') AS ParamValues(x2);
```

To

```
 FROM   @xmlData.nodes('vehicles/vehicle/carPool/employee') AS ParamValues(x2);
```